# Post with grammar error is sad because it cannot be edited to be grammatical (status: by design?)

Tags: support

The following post needs an edit to fix two minor grammatical errors (I could have sworn those weren't there when I posted, but such is the way of the universe that it often fails to mimic the certainty of memory when reevaluated at different times and with a seemingly newer pair of eyes).

In any case:

[What is it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329170/name-for-it-within-grammar)

Needs a bit of an edit, and since the question was locked as opposedly* to* for the reason that: "something about the comments" I am is* failing to see why I am being* not allowed to edit, thusly(*?).

*me, fail English, that's unpossible

Answer (score 5):

The question is not closed; it is locked. That's why you can't edit it.

Locking a question prevents any changes being made, including adding comments. In this case, there are 43 deleted comments. Some of the comments are even duplicates. Comments are ephemeral, and the functionality is really only provided to request clarification of a post. In some cases, a trivial answer might be given as a comment in order to assist a user prior to the question's anticipated closure.

In the case of your question on Main, you have an answer already.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't fix the grammar. So the upshot is you've got an ungrammatical question on your site, taking the quality down, and you won't let me fix it.